# Ruby on Rails 4 Redis Reuse Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I build a Rails 4 application with a Redis Datastore.
The model has some complex objects to store products and some associations to them.
This application is used by up to 50 customers.
Every customer has his own products (up to 2000 products)

Now... I don´t wanna mix up the products in one redis object.
Is it a good idea to create an object per customer so redis does not have one big product object for all customers?
I think about something like a prefix on a customer specific token.
The object for an customer specific product object can called like 'amazon_products'

What do you think? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do operations on these products based on the customer they belong to then yes, I would create one object per customer. I would also use a prefix like `pr:<user-id>` (ie. `pr:123` would contain all the objects for customer with id `123`).

However it depends on the ways you will ask for the data and the operations that you will perform on them.